# How to change the first two words in the string?

Tags: ios, swift, string, substring, enumerate

The problem is somewhat hard to understand since I'm trying to find a way to satisfy the grammar requirements of a foreign language in my app (Russian, in this case). I tried to find answers on the Russian Stackoverflow, but it is dead and has always been like that. It's gonna be a long read but bear with me, please, as I want people to understand what I'm doing and why there's no different solution other than hard coding a bunch of logical workarounds.

The setup is as follows:

1. I have two view controllers (FirstVC and SecondVC).
2. Each view controller has a table.
3. Once the user taps on a cell in the FirstVC, the content of that cell passes on to the table header view in the SecondVC.
4. **BUT: The text in the table header view of the SecondVC should account for Russian declensions** (one of the reasons why Russian is so hard).
5. The table header view of the SecondVC has two strings sitting on top of each other. The top one says "СПИСОК" which translates as "LIST". It is static and will be perpetually left as is. The bottom one says "участников" (translates as "of participants of the") followed by a string interpolation. Altogether it should read as "LIST of participants of the" followed by whatever event name is inherited from the FirstVC's table cell.

This is the hard part. In English, you can put words together in most cases, and there you go, you have a grammatically correct sentence. But Russian is weird in this sense, as you have to **modify the words themselves to account for declensions** (the closest analogy I could think of is when you use singulars and plurals. You can't say: "I had two bottle of water". You would have to add "s" to "bottle". Something like that.

Luckily, the words I need to manipulate are usually the first ones in the string. More rarely, though, one might have to deal with the **combination of the first and the second** word in the string.

Thanks to one of @Leo Dabus's answers on Stackoverflow, I managed to get the first word out of the string, change it and then add to the rest of the words in that string. Now **I need a way to get the first two words out of the string to address those rare cases mentioned above. How do I do that using the same logic?**

Here's the code for the SecondVC:

```
import UIKit

class SecondVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var names: [Cell2Model] = []

var textForChanging: String = ""

var switchedFirstWord: String {
    switch textForChanging.firstWord {
    case "Соревнование": return "соревнования" //translates as "competition"
    default: return "none" } }

var restoOfTheName: String {
    var string = textForChanging
    string.enumerateSubstrings(in: string.startIndex..., options: .byWords) { (_, _, enclosingRange, stop) in
        string.removeSubrange(enclosingRange)
        stop = true }
    return string }

var adjustedEventNameText: String {
    return switchedFirstWord + " " + restoOfTheName }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    
    // names will be taken from UITextFields on the fourth view controller
    names = [
        (Cell2Model(name: "Participant 1")),
        (Cell2Model(name: "Participant 2")),
        (Cell2Model(name: "Participant 3")) ]
    
    let tableHeader = UIView()
    tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeader
    
    let labelOne = UILabel(frame: tableHeader.bounds)
    labelOne.text = "СПИСОК"
    labelOne.font = UIFont(name:"Arial-BoldMT", size: 17.0)
    labelOne.numberOfLines = 0
    labelOne.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    labelOne.textAlignment = .center
    labelOne.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    let labelTwo = UILabel(frame: tableHeader.bounds)
    labelTwo.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    labelTwo.text = "участников \(adjustedEventNameText)"
    labelTwo.font = UIFont(name:"Arial-BoldMT", size: 17.0)
    labelTwo.numberOfLines = 0
    labelTwo.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    labelTwo.textAlignment = .center
    labelTwo.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    tableHeader.addSubview(labelOne)
    tableHeader.addSubview(labelTwo)

    let g = tableHeader.layoutMarginsGuide
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        labelOne.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 11.0),
        labelOne.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
        labelOne.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        labelTwo.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelOne.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        labelTwo.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
        labelTwo.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0), ])
    
    let c = labelTwo.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -11.0)
    c.priority = .required - 1
    c.isActive = true
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if let tableHeader = tableView.tableHeaderView {
        let fitSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: tableView.frame.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let sz: CGSize = tableHeader.systemLayoutSizeFitting(fitSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required, verticalFittingPriority: .defaultLow)
        let height: CGFloat = sz.height
        var headerFrame = tableHeader.frame
        if height != headerFrame.size.height {
            headerFrame.size.height = height
            tableHeader.frame = headerFrame
            tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeader } } }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return names.count }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "secondCell", for: indexPath) as! SecondCell
    let Name = names[indexPath.row]
    cell.label.text = Name.name
    return cell } }

extension StringProtocol {
var byWords: [SubSequence] { components(separated: .byWords) }

func components(separated options: String.EnumerationOptions)-> [SubSequence] {
    var components: [SubSequence] = []
    enumerateSubstrings(in: startIndex..., options: options) { _, range, _, _ in components.append(self[range]) }
    return components }

var firstWord: SubSequence? {
    var word: SubSequence?
    enumerateSubstrings(in: startIndex..., options: .byWords) { _, range, _, stop in
        word = self[range]
        stop = true }
    return word } }
```

Here's the code for the FirstVC if you need it:

```
import UIKit

class FirstVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var names: [Cell1Model] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    
    // names will be taken from UITextFields on the third view controller
    names = [
        Cell1Model(name: "Соревнование по легкой атлетике"), // translates as "athletics competition (or "competition on athletics" to put it into the Russian words order)
        Cell1Model(name: "Благотворительное соревнование по легкой атлетике") // translates as "athletics charity competition" (or "charity competition on athletics" in the Russian words order)
    ]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as? SecondVC {
        vc.textForChanging = names[indexPath.row].name!
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true) } }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return names.count }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
    let Name = names[indexPath.row]
    cell.label.text = Name.name
    return cell }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why hardcode strings? Can’t you use localization? Either a strings file or strings dict?

Comment: very new to swift. Didn't even know this possibility existed at all. Will read into this now. Thanks

Comment: Got it, strings dict is what we use in English to handle plurals. The file takes care of everything. There is a learning curve with localizations but worth the effort.

Comment: Strings dict in Russian can handle zero one two few many etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use split(separator: "по", maxSplits: 1)
and the first results in the resulting array will be
"Соревнование" and "Благотворительно е соревнование" respectively in the two Cell1Model examples

And these lines are already checked in Switch, as you were before

(in any case, the implementation of the image is to be desired)
there is a localizable tool for word declensions in xcode, maybe it will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will check it when I get to my machine!

Comment: I read and watched a little about localizables. I'm not really sure if I absolutely need to use it, since I will have only 15-20 cases at max. As to using split with a "по" separator, "по" doesn't necessarily have to be in the string. Consider for instance a case where you have "Заседание Федерального собрания" and "Оперативное заседание Федерального собрания" instead of "Соревнование по легкой атлетике". I still think that the easiest (maybe not the best though) way would be to somehow get first two words out of the string

Comment: tell me what words should be highlighted in cases "Заседание Федерального собрания" and "Оперативное заседание Федерального собрания"? 

you can also take 1 or 2 first words through split(separator:  " "). But for this program, it must somehow understand where you need to take 2 words and where only one

Comment: do you have an email? I could write you there in Russian (will be a little easier)